# How can I use CoffeeScript's "do" with properties of "this"?

Tags: coffeescript

CoffeeScript has the handy `do` statement to preserve variables in a closure. But how do I preserve properties of `this` with `do`? That always seems to fail.

Example: in a class method I want to attach an event handler to an HTML element using jQuery. The handler should call another method of the same class with a parameter. Now if I write:

```
foo = getBar()
$('div').click -> @handler foo
```

this will obviously not work, because the function will be executed in a different context that doesn't have a method named `handler`. However, if I use `do` and I write this:

```
foo = getBar()
do (@handler, foo) ->
  $('div').click -> @handler foo
```

that will also fail, since @handler translates to this.handler which does not make it through the closure. What's an elegant way to solve this?

Comment: `do` isn't for preserving variables in a closure, `do` is for forcing variables to be evaluated when you expect them to be rather than just dragging a shared reference around: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/TX4Mj/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a [fat arrow](http://coffeescript.org/#fat-arrow) (equals sign)

```
foo = getBar()
$('div').click => @handler foo
```

Or, get a reference to handler before your callback.

```
cbHandler = @handler
foo = getBar()
$('div').click -> cbHandler foo
```